# Check last matching character in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, find

I would like to find if last character of a string is `.`. I know that it is easier to find using `$` in `re`. However, is there a easy way to find `.` without `re`? Also is `re` faster than other string manipulation modules?

```
string1 = "this is a string1."
string2 = "this is a string2."
string3 = "this is a string3."
```

The string always contain `.` at the last only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.endswith`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.endswith):

```
>>> string1 = "this is a string1."
>>> string1.endswith('.')
True

>>> string4 = "this is a string1?"
>>> string4.endswith('.')
False
```

According to [Regular expression HOWTO - Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

> Regular expression patterns are compiled into a series of bytecodes
>   which are then executed by a matching engine written in C. For
>   advanced use, it may be necessary to pay careful attention to how the
>   engine will execute a given RE, and write the RE in a certain way in
>   order to produce bytecode that runs faster.

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem.

Comment: @sundar_ima, Faster-or-not cannot be answered absolutely. It depends on the pattern used / regular expression, string implementation. Try timeit yourself for that.

Comment: @sundar_ima, According to [this benchmark](http://ideone.com/hPTJkK), `str.endswith` is faster than the regular expression `\.$`.